# Temporarily pause a worker in pool to let continue to other args in iterable

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Lets say i have an iterable like so:

```
Sym_file = [A,AA,AKA,ALA]
```

I have this function in my code:

```
def func(sym):
    #'do something'
     while:
          #'do more things'
```

I call the function with a `multiprocessing.map_async()` like so :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2) as pool:
        pool.map_async(get_from_db,iterable=Sym_file).get()
```

As you can see the list is of length 4 and I have 2 workers.
additionally the function has a while function as it need t listen for updates for the passed arguments.

So my question:
Is there a way to temporarily pause the execution of workers so that all of the iterable process?

Comment: Your question apparently got posted before you were done writing it. But if you need all workers to complete some task before they continue to perform some other task, how do you expect that to work with room for only 2 workers in the pool? And why not split the work in a batch of task 1, followed by a batch of task 2, instead of requiring a single batch of tasks paused halfway through?

Comment: If the tasks have to wait on one another, the processing can't be done concurrently.